# How to get out of HDRI mode?

Tags: rendering, shaders, lighting

I realise this is a noob question, but while selecting materials for my objects I accidentally hotkeyed into this HDRI mode (I think). I just want to (pre)render with a regular light but I don't know how to remove this HDRI lighting.
Help is appreciated, thanks!

[image]

Comment: I don't know what happened, but it's gone now. Would still like to know for the future though

Comment: You were in the *Shading* workspace and had the *Material Preview* enabled.

Comment: But is this always present in the shading workspace? I thought it wasn't there before. Thanks btw

Answer (score 1):

Just click the drop-down menu to the right of the shading mode buttons in the top-right.

Then **enable** *Scene Lights* **and** *Scene World* this will override the HDRI to use your scene lighting instead of the look dev lighting setup.

[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 0):

You entered the Material Preview mode from the looks of it.

Hold down the "Z" key and a radial menu will show up. Select whichever mode you want, which sounds like a rendered view mode to me.